# Java Big O notation in algorithm

Tags: java, big-o

i am comfused with this big O notation problem. This code does not look like O(n) but for loop turns number of word time so it is basically not more than 20
so, if we say Length (line.split()) is constant c, can we say O(c.n)  = O(n) ?

```
while (this.scannerMainText.hasNextLine()){
        String line = this.scannerMainText.nextLine();
        for (String word : line.split("[.!,\" ]+")) {
           some statements
         }
     }
```

Comment: n is number of lines in the text

Comment: The first loop runs n times and second loop runs m times. then it will be O(mn).

Comment: yes, @apm i agree with you but, the number of m is less than n

Comment: @umtkas it is irrelevant that `m < n`. What counts is, that `m` does not depend on `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the amount of times a loop is run has a negligible impact on the duration, therefore it is usually not mentioned in the Big-O notation.

For example, if a O(n) loop is run 20 times, you would think the notation would be O(20n), but because the impact is so small it is not mentioned it the Big-O notation and therefore O(20n) = O(n). Same goes for O(20n²) = O(n²) etc..

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Time complexity is based only on the number of times an algorithm is run; the actual number/cost of steps within the algorithm (`c`, as you call it) is not considered for Big-O notation.

**Added**

I'm not familiar enough with the edge cases of the theory to say that if all of the lines are equal in length you can reduce the runtime of the inner loop to a constant. *In general, this algorithm would be considered O(mn).*

Comment: This is a quite confusing formulation. More precisely the time complexity is an upper bound for the number of steps the algorithm performs with some constant factor `c`. So if you write O(n) that means, your algorithm does not perform more steps than `c*n` for some constant `c`.